# How to pass GooglePlay Campaign Parameters using Intent from Android Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent, google-play, deep-linking

[GooglePlay Campaign Parameters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns) allow you to pass referrer/attribution information to Play Store URLs. Once the app is installed from the Play Store, the params will be broadcasted to the app as intent extras.

This works great only if you always want to go to the Play store, even when the app is installed.

For my use case, I would like that when a user clicks on a button, if the app is installed, it would launch the app, otherwise, it goes to the store with the referrer params.

On Android Chrome, the only way to get the above behavior is to use the Android Intent for Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents However, in the documentation, it is not clear on how to pass referrer info to the Play Store, if possible.

Does anyone have any insight on how I can pass the referrer info that was supported by the Play Store using the Android intent in Chrome?

Comment: https://paul.kinlan.me/deep-app-linking-on-android-and-chrome/

Comment: Any progress in the matter?